# Obtener la ID de un Pedido, en el momento de enviarlo por PHP a BBDD (Para un CSV)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, csv, fputcsv

Intento hacer lo siguiente:

- Al enviar un **FORM**, genera un pedido, el cuál, a través de Ajax, envío a la base de datos.
- A continuación, tengo otro Ajax, (ambos dentro del jQuery cuando se hace submit) que me saca un archivo csv del pedido:

  ```
  <?php
  $cod_cliente = ($_POST['cod_cliente']);
  $optica = ($_POST['optica']);
  $fecha = ($_POST['fecha']);
  $tipo = ($_POST['tipo']);


  $csv = "../pedidos/PEDIDO ".$tipo.".csv";

  $lista = array (
      array('Codigo Cliente', 'Cliente', 'Fecha', 'Tipo'),
      array($cod_cliente, $optica, $fecha, $tipo),
  );

  $fp = fopen($csv, 'x');

  foreach ($lista as $campos) {
      fputcsv($fp, $campos);
  }

  fclose($fp);
  ```

  ?>

El **ajax** completo: al hacer submit:

```
$("#pedidos").submit(function(e){

  // Aquí definidas todas las variables

  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php/enviar_pedido.php',
    data: {'cod_cliente': cod_cliente,
            ...etc
            }
  })
  .done(function(listas_rep){
  })
  .fail(function(){
  })

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php/generarCsv.php',
    data: {'cod_cliente': cod_cliente,
           'optica': optica,
           'fecha': fecha,
           'tipo': tipoCi}
  })
  .done(function(listas_rep){
    alert('CSV Generado con exito');
  })
  .fail(function(){
    alert('Error al crear el archivo CSV')
  })
})
```

Mi cuestión, es la siguiente: este pedido se envía a su vez que genera el archivo csv.

Si os fijáis, el nombre del archivo csv, es: PEDIDO "tipo", aun que lo que necesito es que obtenga el formato de: "PEDIDO 01" "PEDIDO 02"

- La ID del pedido, se supone que es un `AUTOINCREMENT` en la base de datos, con lo que ahí está el "ID" pero el `CSV` lo genero en el instante que creo el pedido, obviamente, en ese momento todavía no está la ID.

¿Alguien me puede porfavor ofrecer algún consejo / solucion?

Comment: Cuál es el ajax con el que lo envías a la BD?

Comment: Acabo de editar mi pregunta, en la que añado todo el ajax al hacer submit, ¿Sería útil añadir también el PHP el cuál envío los datos? (Añadir, que el campo con la ID del pedido en la bbdd se llama npedido )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu archivo que guarda en la BD pon lo siguiente.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(['id' => $tu_id]);
```

Esto regresará el id, en el data. 
Dado que las llamadas ajax son asyncronas, deberás concatenarlas en el done

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php/enviar_pedido.php',
    data: {'cod_cliente': cod_cliente,
            ...etc
            }
})
.done(function(data){
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/generarCsv.php',
        data: {'cod_cliente': cod_cliente,
           'optica': optica,
           'fecha': fecha,
           'tipo': tipoCi
           'id_de_la_bd' : data.id // aquí lo pasas
        }
    })
    .done(function(listas_rep){
       alert('CSV Generado con exito');
    })
     .fail(function(){
        alert('Error al crear el archivo CSV')
     });
})
.fail(function(){
})
```

Ya solo concaténale el nombre de la forma que mejor te parezca en tu archivo php

Comment: Excelente aporte! Muchas gracias! Si funciona!